# Maintain Dialog and a Thread across different Activities or fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I'm making an app for 7" tablets. I'm following the example given here http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html.

There are two fragments.

TitlesFragment  containing list
DetailsFragment containing webview to show result on click of an item in list

In landscape mode they are one next to another. Click in TitlesFragment list item will show details in the DetailsFragment. All in the same activity.

In portrait mode however, clicking in TitlesFragment opens a new Activity called DetailsActivity that has DetailsFragment which shows the details.

When he's on DetailsActivity switching to landscape mode finishes DetailsActivity and he's back on TitlesActivity where he will see the split view like explained before.

Problem now is -

Suppose he's on DetailsActivity in portrait mode. He starts a download and a dialog with active download progress bar is being shown. Now he switches to Landscape mode. The details activity finishes and my download dialog is gone. How can I handle this case?

This seems to be a common problem but I couldn't find a solution after searching. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose he's on DetailsActivity in portrait mode. He starts a download
>   and a dialog with active download progress bar is being shown. Now he
>   switches to Landscape mode. The details activity finishes and my
>   download dialog is gone. How can I handle this case?

I'm assuming that the download continues(probably in a `Service`?!) even if the user finishes the `DetailsActivity` by switching to landscape. In this case you could let the landscape activity(which will hold both fragments) know about this and indicate somehow that the download is still in progress and an indicator should be shown. That indicator could be a dialog/`ProgressBar` on top of only the `DetailsFragment` for that position(so the user can still fully use the app) or on the entire screen.

Or you could lose the dialog and simply show a notification letting the use know a download is in progress without the need for the dialog. If the download is important and the user should wait this is not an option.